# Create .jar file idea project command line

Tags: java, compilation, executable-jar

I want to create a jar file from this project https://github.com/5up3rc/weblogic_cmd

I have seen that there is a `weblogic_cmd/.idea/artifacts/weblogic_cmd_jar.xml` file which is probably what I need but I haven't seen any tutorial on how to do it via command line.

I have also tried to compile it manually

`find src -name \*.java -print0 | xargs -0 javac -cp -classpath ./lib/*.jar -o ./classes/`

but I failed.